# Yammer url for post something

Tags: api, url, post, httpwebrequest, yammer

i want to find out how to post something in yammer group wall via php application.I searched in yammer api and couldn't get clear idea.can someone please help me with the url format to post something to yammer wall

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They will tell you when you register for an API key:

Request token URL https://www.yammer.com/oauth/request_token

Access token URL https://www.yammer.com/oauth/access_token

Authorize URL https://www.yammer.com/oauth/authorize

We support plain text (recommended) as well as HMAC-SHA1. Only SSL requests are allowed.

Callback URL: None specified

Comment: Actually, this is what you're looking for, below. The URLs above will help you authenticate. This URL below is the API call to post: https://www.yammer.com/api/v1/messages.json?access_token=xxxxxxx